# combo box in a date format

Tags: excel, vba

my user form has three separate combo boxes for the users to select the following: Year, Month, Date (they are not dependent). For example if the user selects 2017 (the year), May(the month) and 23(the day) I want vba to enter in column two on my database sheet: "2017/05/23". I want it exactly in this format as a value.

The code below doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 With ws
 .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.cboYear / Me.cboMonth / Me.cboDay.Value
 End With
```

Comment: Protip: "doesn't work" isn't a very good way to describe what your code does. "produces unexpected garbage" would be more accurate. In general, you'll want to avoid "my code doesn't work" in SO questions, and instead *describe* what you're getting - garbage output, run-time error, etc.

Comment: Do you have any data validation to prevent me from selecting `2017/02/29` or `2017/04/31`? Is there a specific reason you don't want to use a calendar control which will provide this for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're dividing the year by the month, and then dividing that by the day. That's the value your cell is getting.

Build an actual *date* instead.

```
.Cells(lRow, 2).Value = DateSerial(cboYear, cboMonth, cboDay)
```

And then format that date any way you wish, using `NumberFormat`:

```
.Cells(lRow, 2).NumberFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
```

---

`DateSerial` expects integer values. If your `cboMonth` contains strings (month names), then you need to work a bit harder for it - the easiest is probably just to use a keyed collection - specify a string key when `.Add`ing the integers to the collection:

```
Static months As Collection
If months Is Nothing Then
    Set months = New Collection
    With months
        .Add 1, "January"
        .Add 2, "February"
        .Add 3, "March"
        '...
        .Add 12, "December"
    End With        
End If
```

And then you have an easy lookup:

```
Dim monthId As Integer
monthId = months(cboMonth)
```

So your `DateSerial` would be:

```
.Cells(lRow, 2).Value = DateSerial(cboYear, monthId, cboDay)
```

Comment: Thanks Mat but it gives a 'Run time error 13. Type mismatch'. Any ideas why?

Comment: What's in these dropdowns? `DateSerial` expects integers. If your month dropdown contains `May` then you need a way to associate that to `5`. Consider having 2 columns in your dropdown, first being 0-width and containing values 1-12, second containing month names. Use the combobox' `Value` to get the selected integer. Failing that, a keyed `Collection` mapping `May` (string key) to `5` (integer value) could work just as well.

Comment: Yes I have April, May, June  etc until March and not integers. I'm not sure I understand how a keyed Collection would work. If you could show the code for that it would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: @thankseveryone edited. It's much less code to make a multicolumn combobox though, and more robust, too.

Comment: yeah that should work. now please don't edit your question *in response* to answers, it removes all the value from the question. Other people with similar issues will google up and come here. See [help/someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you're not sure what to do next.

Comment: I put the code like in my edited initial question above and the error now is 'run time error 438. Object doesn't support this property or method' and it highlights in yellow the line about .cells(lrow, 2).value = Date serial(cboYear, monthID, cboDay). Is there anything I can do to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Makes no sense. Specify `Option Explicit`, declare all variables, watch for typos.

Comment: IDK, try specifying `.Value` explicitly when reading the combobox values. Or ask a new question, since that's an entirely new problem. Error 438 is typically caused by blindly copy-pasting code instead of typing it and letting IntelliSense guide you. I gave you a *concept*, something to answer your original question.