# Multiple variables from a single user input

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing some VBA code that should go through all Excel files in a specific folder (folder names always formatted with Month Year, e.g. May 2020). In my code I also need to use the individual "Month" and "Year" strings e.g. "May" and "2020", and the date format mm/??/yy e.g. 5/??/20 (the day doesn't matter, so I just put ? as a placeholder) which are stored as variables.
So far, I am using `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)` to let the user choose the folder, and I'm using `InputBox("")` three times to get the strings and date.
Is there a way to condense this so that the user only has to do one to two things, instead of four?
According to this answer [combo box in a date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44164429/combo-box-in-a-date-format) it seems like a combo box could work (maybe getting the month and year inputs as strings and getting the folder and date based on that?), but is there a better a way?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can either use a userform to collect the information, or have the user enter (eg "May 2020 mm/dd/yyyy" and use `Split()` to separate out the 3 parts.

Comment: Your logic appears flawed. If you want the user to pick the file, don't use the FolderPicker. Use the FilePicker instead and open the file he chooses or use the File Open dialog. On the other hand, if the file name can be created from a date, you can ask for a date to be entered, create the file name using code, and then open the file by the name specified in the date. Either way there is need for only one input by the user.

Comment: @Variatus - it looks like there could be multiple matched files in the selected folder

Comment: You can create "path" Variable for Parent folder of "May 2020". Then instead of all those four things you could do one thing. Use inputbox for date like `Dim dt As Date dt = Application.InputBox("Enter Date", , , , , , , 2)` . Then use VBA Format function to create different variables out of InputBox value. For Example, for today 25th June 2020, `Format(dt, "mmmm")` will give you "June", `Format(dt, "yyyy")` will give you "2020", `Format(dt, "m/d/yyyy")` will give you "6/25/2020" according to your regional format settings. `Format(dt, "mmmm yyyy")` will give you "June 2020"

Comment: @Variatus I don't want the user to pick the file. I want them to pick a preexisting folder that is named using the format Month Year (the VBA program itself will loop through all files in that folder and collect specific data)

Comment: @Tim Williams and Naresh Bhople thank you for your suggestions, I will try them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way it might work.

1. Ask the user for a date
2. From the date the macro creates the folder name
3. The path of the folder is stored in the macro

The code below implements and supports that work flow.

```
Sub GetFolderName()

    Dim Inp             As String
    Dim FolderName      As String
    Dim FilePath        As String
    
    
    ' make sure you ask for a date format that your computer can recognise
    ' it depends upon your Regional Settings (in Windows Control Panel)
    Do
        Inp = InputBox("Enter a date", "Date format dd/mm/yy", _
                       Format(Date, "dd/mm/yy"))
        If Inp = "" Then Exit Sub           ' blank or Cancel
        
        If Not IsDate(Inp) Then
            MsgBox "Sorry, I can't recognise your entry" & vbCr & _
                   "as a date. Please observe the date" & vbCr & _
                   "format requirement and try again."
        End If
    Loop While Not IsDate(Inp)
    
    FilePath = Environ("userprofile") & "\Desktop\"
    FolderName = Format(CDate(Inp), "mmmm yyyy")
    
    MsgBox "Folder name is """ & FolderName & """" & vbCr & _
           "File path = " & FilePath
    
    ' complete path is
    Debug.Print FilePath & FolderName
End Sub
```

Note that the following options were not utilized but are still available.

```
Day(Cdate(Inp))    ' returns the day of the entered date
Month(Cdate(Inp))  ' returns the number of the month of the entered date
Year(Cdate(Inp))   ' returns the year of the entered date (45-digit)
```

Comment: Thank you, I adapted this to my code and it worked perfectly!